# PHP multidimentional array has all subarrays of another multidimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to make sure that array $b has all the subarrays from $a despite the numeric keys (0,1,2.. etc)

```
$a = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 443]
];

$b = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 25, 'f' => 3],
    2 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 443]
];
```

My approach with foreach inside foreach inside foreach and multiple ifs... quickly becomes a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `array_diff()`, unfortunately this only works with 1 dimension.  But you can `json_encode()` each element of the array and compare that...

```
$c = array_diff(array_map("json_encode", $a), array_map("json_encode", $b));

print_r($c);
```

With your original data, as they are all in the second array, this gives...

```
Array
(
)
```

Change the 443 to 4431

```
$a = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 4431]
];
```

and you get...

```
Array
(
    [1] => {"v":144,"f":4431}
)
```

The key will be the same as the original, but the data is JSON encoded (if that really matters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection in this case.

```
$a = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 443]
];

$b = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 25, 'f' => 3],
    2 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 443]
];
$result = array_intersect($a, $b);
if($result == $a){
  echo '$b has all the value in $a';
}
```

Comment: This gives loads of `Notice: Array to string conversion` messages.

Comment: yes did not test before posting. The code should be
$a = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 443]
];

$b = [
    0 => ['v' => 1, 'f' => 2],
    1 => ['v' => 25, 'f' => 3],
    2 => ['v' => 144, 'f' => 443]
];

$result = array_uintersect($a, $b, 'compareDeepValue');
if($result == $a){
  echo '$b has all the value in $a';
}

function valueCompare($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['v'], $val2['v']) && strcmp($val1['f'], $val2['f']);
}